# Best way of creating polymorphic C++ objects with types based on a string?

Tags: c++, types, polymorphism

I want to create objects with polymorphic types based on a string I read from some config text file. A naive simple solution to this is to assign a string to each possible type and then compare the config string in an else-if chain to all the defined types. Something like:

```
class Base
{
   virtual std::string GetStringType() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
   std::string GetStringType() override { return "Derived1"; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
   std::string GetStringType() override { return "Derived2"; }
};

// etc ...

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
   auto derived1 = std::make_unique<Derived1>();
   auto derived2 = std::make_unique<Derived2>();
   // etc ...

   std::string stringType(argv[1]);

   if (stringType == derived1->GetStringType())
       ptr = std::make_unique<decltype(derived1)>();
   else if (stringType == derived2->GetStringType())
       ptr = std::make_unique<decltype(derived2)>();
   // etc ...
}
```

However, with this approach, each time a new derived class is added, a new else-if branch needs to be manually added, and I am trying to avoid that. Is there a better, more automatic approach to this?

Also, in an ideal scenario, when a new derived class is defined somewhere (just defined, not instantiated), I would like to check against it automatically also. Is this somehow possible? I'd be happy for any solution that works, macros included.

Comment: How about simply a global `std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>>`

Comment: Have a central registry in the code (e.g., `std::map<std::string, factory_fn>`), and each class self registers with its unique string and a factory function.

Comment: @Frank can you elaborate

Comment: @Jixxy -- Start with the basics.  Do you know what a `std::map` is and what it's used for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68518973/2752075

Answer (score 2):

A simple map-based factory can do the trick:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Base 
{
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  static std::unique_ptr<Base> create(const std::string& name) {
      return factories_.at(name)();
  }

  template<typename T>
  static void registerDerived() {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, T>);

    factories_[T::GetStringType()] = std::make_unique<T>;
  }

private:
  static std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>> factories_;
};

std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>> Base::factories_;

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
   static std::string GetStringType() { return "Derived1"; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
   static std::string GetStringType() { return "Derived2"; }
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Base::registerDerived<Derived1>();
  Base::registerDerived<Derived2>();
  // etc...

  std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr = Base::create(argv[1]);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice solution. What do you think is the best way to "automate" the registering process here (register every defined derived class)?

Comment: @Jixxy There are ways to do pseudo-automated automatic registration, but it gets messy and error-prone fast (initialization order fiasco, "unused" TUs being stripped from the build, etc...). I honestly recommend against it unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example based on unordered_map, with an explicit class factory.
Decoupling the creation of the instances completely from the base class.
(Separation of concerns)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Hello() = 0;
};

class Class1 : public Base
{
public:
    void Hello() override
    {
        std::cout << "Class1\n";
    }
};

class Class2 : public Base
{
public:
    void Hello() override
    {
        std::cout << "Class2\n";
    }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ClassFactory final
{
public:

    // For each class registered at a function to the map
    // that will create a unique_ptr to a new instance of that class
    template<typename class_t>
    void Register(const std::string& string)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, class_t>, "You can only register classes derived from Base");

        // create_function is a lambda
        auto create_function = [] { return std::make_unique<class_t>(); };

        // add the function to the map, with the string as key
        create_function_map.insert({ string,create_function });
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Base> Create(const std::string& string)
    {
        // if nothing is found for the string then throw an exception
        if (create_function_map.find(string) == create_function_map.end())
        {
            std::ostringstream os;
            os << "No class registered for string : " << string;
            throw std::invalid_argument(os.str());
        }

        // otherwise call the function that will make an instance of the 
        // derived class
        auto create_function = create_function_map.at(string);
        return create_function();
    }

    static ClassFactory& Instance()
    {
        static ClassFactory instance;
        return instance;
    }
    

private:
    ClassFactory() = default;
    ~ClassFactory() = default;

    // use unordered_map it has lookup complexity of O(1)
    // std::map has a lookup complexity of O(n log(n))
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>> create_function_map;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    // For each new class register a name, this is the only code
    // you need to expand to add new classes
    // factory is a singleton so you can reuse it throughout your code
    // without having to pass it around.
    auto& factory = ClassFactory::Instance();
    factory.Register<Class1>("Class1");
    factory.Register<Class2>("Class2");

    // create an instance of an object of type Class1.
    auto object1 = factory.Create("Class1");
    object1->Hello();

    // create an instance of an object of type Class2.
    auto object2 = factory.Create("Class2");
    object2->Hello();

    return 0;
}
```